# Replace node's native domain module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

There's a [native node module called `domain`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/domain.js) that is being deprecated. I'm interested in copying it and running a local version with some changes.

I just tried to copy the module from source and `require` the copy and I get this error.

```
Assertion failed: (args[1]->IsObject()), function SetupDomainUse, file ../src/node.cc, line 950.
Abort trap: 6
```

Here's what I'm running:

```
$ node -pe process.versions 
{ http_parser: '2.5.0',
  node: '2.5.0',
  v8: '4.2.77.21',
  uv: '1.6.1',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  modules: '44',
  openssl: '1.0.2d' }
```

How do I replace node's native domain module with the local one that I copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `domain` module on the master branch, but you're using io.js v2.5.0 so you should use the module belonging to that version ([here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodejs/node/v2.5.0/lib/domain.js)).

After that, you need to comment out [this line](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v2.5.0/lib/domain.js#L35) before it will load properly.

Comment: I upgraded io.js to the latest 3.2.0 and had to comment out line 31 and add `var _domain_flag = {};`. Thanks!